# dimnames for multidimensional arrays in R

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, names

I know that using dimnames it is possible to set rownames, colnames and dimnames for multidimensional arrays in R . However, they are same for  "row names/col names" to all the matrices in n dimensions. Is it possible to set different rownames in my case?

For eg: I am creating a 3 dimensional array:

1. `X <- array(0, dim = c(3, 3, 3), dimnames= list(c("a","b","c"), c("A","B","C"), c("A","B","C")))`

   The output of (1) is 3x3x3  array with rownames("a","b","c"), colnames("A","B","C") and with dimnames for 3rd dimension("A","B","C").
2. What I need is to replace the rownames with rownames_respective_dim3 name; say rownames in array 1 have (a_A,b_A) where array 2 have (a_B, b_B), etc,

my intended code in a for loop is as below:

```
dim3 <- dimnames(X)[[3]] wherethe output is  dim3 = "A" "B" "C"

    for (d in seq_along(1:length(dim3))){
        for (r in seq_along(1:length(rownames(X))){
          rownames(X[ , , d])[r] <- paste(rownames(X[ , , d])[r], dim3[d], sep="_")
             }
       }
```

I do not get the required results though the code does not show any error while execution! Thank you.

Comment: You can't. Take a look at `rownames(X)` - they are constant across all strata of your array.

Comment: so if 3 matrices with 3 different rownames could be appended as an array, this would be possible it seems. My need is to generate a array and automate the task of appending the rownames with respective dimension name.

Comment: No, I mean an array must have the same rownames in each stratum. That's the way they work.  See `?array` - "*The ‘"dimnames"’ attribute is optional: if present it is a list with **one component for each dimension ... a character vector of the length given by the element of the ‘"dim"’ attribute for that dimension.***"

Comment: Ya that is right! Even binding using abind() package works well in 1 or 2 dimension but not in 3rd dimension. Thanks

Comment: You could flatten the 3 dimensional array to 2 dimensions and then reassign the rownames based on the original array though. That might be a satisfactory workaround?

Comment: is possible using matrix(X, nrows * ncols, ndims)  or array(X, c(nrow*ncol, ndims);  however, the row and col names are not retained. :)